# How to validate more than one errors in pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop

I'm learning oojs and I have a method that searches for the same name and isbn of a book object. And I wanted the method to find the values equal and case the two are equal to show the error messages. I tried it that way but no error message is shown.

And there are several other attributes but I chose to omit so as not to pollute

class Book

```
export default class Book{
    constructor(title, isbn ){
        this.title = title;
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    set title(title){
        if (isEmpty(title) || isNull(title))
        throw new Error(`cannot be empty`);
      this._title = title;
    }
    set isbn(isbn){
        if (isEmpty(isbn) || !isbn.match(isbnFormat))
        throw new Error(`needs format valid`);
      this._isbn = isbn;
    }
 
    get title(){
        return this._title;
    }
  
    get isbn(){
        return this._isbn; 
    }
}
```

class BookDAO

```
import Book from "../models/Book.js";
import ValidateErrors from "../validateErrors.js";

export default class BookDAO {
  constructor() {
    this._list = [];
  }
  someTitle(book) {
    return this._list.some((b) => b.title === book.title);
  }
  someIsbn(book) {
    return this._list.some((b) => b.isbn === book.isbn);
  }

  validationBook(book) {
    const validate = new ValidateErrors();

    if (this.someTitle(book.title)) {
      validate.addError(
        new Error(`already exists`)
      );
    }
    if (this.someIsbn(book.isbn)) {
      validate.addError(
        new Error(`already exists`)
      );
    }

    return validate;
   
  }

  add(book) {
    const validatedBook = this.validationBook(book);
    if (!(book instanceof Book)) {
      throw new Error(`object is not valid`);
    }
    if (validatedBook.hasErrors()) {
      return validatedBook.errors.forEach((error) => {
        throw error;
      });
    }

    this._list.push(book);
  }
```

class ValidateErrors

```
export default class ValidateErrors{
    constructor(){
        this._errors = [];
    }
   
    addError(error){
        this._errors.push(error);
    }

    hasErrors(){
        return this._errors.length > 0;
    }

    get errors(){
        return this._errors;
    }
}
```

class test

```
try {
  const bookDAO = new BookDAO();
  const newBook = new Book(
    "Devops",
    "978-85-13196-08-9"
  );
  const newBook2 = new Book(
    "Devops",
    "978-85-13196-08-9"
  );
  bookDAO.add(newBook2)
  console.log(`saved ${newBook.title}, ${newBook.isbn}`);
    bookDAO.add(newBook);
  console.log(`saved ${newBook.title}, ${newBook.isbn}`);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(`${err}`);
}
```

The test passes even with equal values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong key when checking for whether a book is already present.

Firstly, you need to pass the whole `book` object in your `if` condition in the `validationBook` method,

```
if (this.someTitle(book)) {
  validate.addError(
    new Error(`already exists`)
  );
}
if (this.someIsbn(book)) {
  validate.addError(
    new Error(`already exists`)
  );
}
```

Secondly, you need to check against `_title` and `_isbn` as opposed to `title` and `isbn`

```
  someTitle(book) {
    return this._list.some((b) => b._title === book._title);
  }
  someIsbn(book) {
    return this._list.some((b) => b._isbn === book._isbn);
  }
```

```js
const isEmpty = val => val === '';
const isNull = val => typeof val === null;

class Book {
  constructor(title, isbn) {
    this.title = title;
    this.isbn = isbn;
  }

  set title(title) {
    if (isEmpty(title) || isNull(title))
      throw new Error(`cannot be empty`);
    this._title = title;
  }
  set isbn(isbn) {
    if (isEmpty(isbn))
      throw new Error(`needs format valid`);
    this._isbn = isbn;
  }

  get title() {
    return this._title;
  }

  get isbn() {
    return this._isbn;
  }
}

class BookDAO {
  constructor() {
    this._list = [];
  }
  someTitle(book) {
    return this._list.some((b) => b._title === book._title);
  }
  someIsbn(book) {
    return this._list.some((b) => b._isbn === book._isbn);
  }

  validationBook(book) {
    const validate = new ValidateErrors();
    if (this.someTitle(book)) {
      validate.addError(
        new Error(`Title already exists`)
      );
    }
    if (this.someIsbn(book)) {
      validate.addError(
        new Error(`ISBN already exists`)
      );
    }

    return validate;

  }

  add(book) {
    const validatedBook = this.validationBook(book);
    if (!(book instanceof Book)) {
      throw new Error(`object is not valid`);
    }
    if (validatedBook.hasErrors()) {
      throw validatedBook.errors;
    }

    this._list.push(book);
  }
}

class ValidateErrors {
  constructor() {
    this._errors = [];
  }

  addError(error) {
    this._errors.push(error);
  }

  hasErrors() {
    return this._errors.length > 0;
  }

  get errors() {
    return this._errors;
  }
}

try {
  const bookDAO = new BookDAO();
  const newBook = new Book(
    "Devops",
    "978-85-13196-08-9"
  );
  const newBook2 = new Book(
    "Devops",
    "978-85-13196-08-9"
  );
  bookDAO.add(newBook2)
  console.log({
    list: bookDAO._list
  });
  console.log(`saved ${newBook.title}, ${newBook.isbn}`);
  bookDAO.add(newBook);
  console.log({
    list: bookDAO._list
  });
  console.log(`saved ${newBook.title}, ${newBook.isbn}`);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(`${err}`);
}
```

Comment: Hi, pai.not.pi! Thanks so much for your answer! It showed the duplicate title message (o//) but can the message of the same isbn be shown? I thought of making this object of errors so that they could be shown if both were equal

Comment: @Laura - so you can't throw multiple errors since the control flow changes once the code hits the `catch` block. You can however do `throw validatedBook.errors;` and catch both errors. I've updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the entire book object to `someTitle`.
Change from

```
if (this.someTitle(book.title)) {
```

to

```
if (this.someTitle(book)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're iterating through the error list then the process will be killed at your very first throwing. If you want to throw multiple errors at once then you'll need to throw ValidateErrors directly instead. ValidateErrors should extend from the native Error class.

```
export default class ValidateErrors extends Error{
    constructor(message){
        super(message);
        this._errors = [];
    }
   
    addError(error){
        this._errors.push(error);
    }

    hasErrors(){
        return this._errors.length > 0;
    }

    get errors(){
        return this._errors;
    }
}

  add(book) {
    const validatedBook = this.validationBook(book);
    if (!(book instanceof Book)) {
      throw new Error(`object is not valid`);
    }
    if (validatedBook.hasErrors()) {
      throw validateBook;
    }

    this._list.push(book);
  }
```